# How to hide table header in view with no javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is a index.html.erb. How do I hide the header, such as Description, with a method in helper file? Preferably without using javascript.

```
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Description</th>

  </tr>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <% if show_desc? %>
      <th>Description</th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
```

UPDATE: Another way is to define and use in your view a helper like:

```
def description
 show_desc? ? "<th>Description</th> : ""
end
```

You can refactor this method how you like.

Comment: That's not a sensible rule, if it exists... although if you're desperate you could just bung it in a helper.